# How to apply regex function to dataframe column to return value

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to apply a regex function to a column of a dataframe to determine gender pronouns. This is what my dataframe looks like:

```
    name                                            Descrip
0  Sarah           she doesn't like this because her mum...
1  David                 he does like it because his dad...
2    Sam  they generally don't like it because their par...
```

These are the codes I ran to make that dataframe:

```
list_label = ["Sarah", "David", "Sam"]
list_descriptions = ["she doesn't like this because her mum...", "he does like it because his dad...", "they generally don't like it because their parent..."]

data3 = {'name':list_label, 'Descrip':list_descriptions}
test_df = pd.DataFrame(data3)
```

I'm trying to determine the genders of the person by applying a regex function on the "Descrip" column. Specifically, these are the patterns I want to implement:

```
"male":"(he |his |him )",
"female":"(she |her |hers )",
"plural, or singular non-binary":"(they |them |their )"
```

The full code I've written is as follows:

This function attempts to match each pattern and returns the name of the gender pronoun mentioned most often in a row value description. Each gender pronoun has several key words in a pattern string (eg. him, her, they).The idea is to determine the max_gender, or the gender associated with the pattern group most mentioned throughout the values in the Descrip column. Thus, max_gender can take on one of three values: male | female | plural, or singular non-binary. If none of the patterns are identified throughout the Descrip row values, then "unknown" will be returned instead.

```
import re
def get_pronouns(text):
    patterns = {
        "male":"(he |his |him )",
        "female":"(she |her |hers )",
        "plural, or singular non-binary":"(they |them |their )"
    }
    max_gender = "unknown"
    max_gender_count = 0
    for gender in patterns:
        pattern = re.compile(gender)
        mentions = re.findall(pattern, text)
        count_mentions = len(mentions)
        if count_mentions > max_gender_count:
            max_gender_count = count_mentions
            max_gender = gender
    return max_gender

test_df["pronoun"] = test_df.loc[:, "Descrip"].apply(get_pronouns)
print(test_df)
```

However, when I run the code, it obviously fails to determine the gender pronoun. This is shown in the following output:

```
    name                                            Descrip  pronoun
0  Sarah           she doesn't like this because her mum...  unknown
1  David                 he does like it because his dad...  unknown
2    Sam  they generally don't like it because their par...  unknown
```

**Does anyone know what is wrong with my code?**

Comment: Can you explain the algorithm you're using in `get_pronouns()`? I'll try figuring it out, there are also a few other things I would change. I'm also confused as to why the descriptions are cut off.

Comment: I've added some comments -- thanks! This is an example case, hence why the descriptions are cut off. I'm super open to substantially different approaches.

Comment: Sounds good, I'm almost done. If you are looking for different approaches, it might help if you talk a bit more about your actual situation, not just the example.

Comment: I'm doing a web-scraping exercise. Specifically I'm extracting the entire text source of a long list of wikipedia biography articles. So I have a dataframe with two columns. Column one is the name of the article. Column two is the entire source content of that article. I need to make a third column, the one that determines if the person the article is about is a male, female, or plural. This is why I need this regex code, to apply it to column two (content) to create column three (gender pronoun).

Comment: I'm starting to question whether a DataFrame is the right data structure for this. Of course if you intend to manipulate the results, you could have the article text column hold a key to a dictionary which contains all the texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to discover why your code isn't working, add a print statement to your function like so:

```py
    for gender in patterns:
        print(gender)
        pattern = re.compile(gender)
```

Your regex also needs some tweaks. For example, in the first line of the song Breathe by Pink Floyd, *Breathe, breathe in the air*, your regex finds two male pronouns.

There may be other problems too, I'm not sure.

---

Here is a solution quite similar to yours. The regex are fixed, the dictionary is replaced by a list of tuples, etc.

---

### Solution code

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
import operator as op

names_list = ['Sarah', 'David', 'Sam']
descs_list = ["she doesn't like this because her mum...", 'he does like it because his dad...',
              "they generally don't like it because their parent..."]

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=zip(names_list, descs_list), columns=['Name', 'Desc'])

pronoun_re_list = [('male', re.compile(r"\b(?:he|his|him)\b", re.IGNORECASE)),
                   ('female', re.compile(r"\b(?:she|her|hers)\b", re.IGNORECASE)),
                   ('plural/nb', re.compile(r"\b(?:they|them|their)\b", re.IGNORECASE))]


def detect_pronouns(str_in: str) -> str:
    match_results = ((curr_pron, len(curr_patt.findall(str_in))) for curr_pron, curr_patt in pronoun_re_list)
    max_pron, max_counts = max(match_results, key=op.itemgetter(1))
    if max_counts == 0:
        return np.NaN
    else:
        return max_pron


df_1['Pronouns'] = df_1['Desc'].map(detect_pronouns)
```

---

### Explanations

#### Code

`match_results` is a **generator expression**. `curr_pron` stands for "current pronoun", and `curr_patt` for "current pattern". It might make things clearer if I rewrite it as a for loop which creates a list:

```py
    match_results = []
    for curr_pron, curr_patt in pronoun_re_list:
        match_counts = len(curr_patt.findall(str_in))
        match_results.append((curr_pron, match_counts))
```

`for curr_pron, curr_patt in ...` is taking advantage of something which goes by a few different names, usually multiple assignment or tuple unpacking. You can find a nice article on it [here](https://treyhunner.com/2018/03/tuple-unpacking-improves-python-code-readability/). In this case, it's just a different way of writing:

```py
    for curr_tuple in pronoun_re_list:
        curr_pron = curr_tuple[0]
        curr_patt = curr_tuple[1]
```

#### RegEx

Time for everyone's favorite subject; Regex! I use a wonderful website called [RegEx101](https://regex101.com), you can mess around with the patterns there, it makes things so much easier to understand. I have set up a page with some test data and the regex I'll be covering below: https://regex101.com/r/Y1onRC/2.

Now, let's take a look at the regex I used: `\b(?:he|his|him)\b`.

The `he|his|him` part is exactly like in yours, it matches the words 'he', 'his' or 'him'. In your regex, that is surrounded by parentheses, mine also includes `?:` after the opening parenthesis. `(pattern stuff)` is a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html), which as the name implies, means it captures whatever it matches. Since here we don't actually care about the contents of the matches, only whether there is or isn't a match, we add `?:` to create a non-capturing group, which doesn't capture (or save) the contents.

I said that the `he|his|him` part of the regex is the same as yours, but that isn't exactly true. You include a space after each pronoun, presumably to avoid it matching the letters `he` in the middle of a word. Unfortunately, as I mentioned above, it finds two matches in the sentence *Breathe, breathe in the air*. Our saviour is `\b`, which matches [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). This means we catch the *he* in *Words words words he.*, whereas `(he |his |him )` doesn't.

Finally, we compile the patterns with the [`re.IGNORECASE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE) flag, which I don't think requires much explanation, although please do let me know if I'm wrong.

Here is how I would describe the two patterns in plain english:

- `(he |his |him )` matches the letters *he* followed by a space, *his* followed by a space, or *him* followed by a space, and returns the full match plus a group.
- `\b(?:he|his|him)\b` with the `re.IGNORECASE` flag matches the words *he*, *his*, or *him*, regardless of case, and returns the full match.

Hope that was clear enough, let me know!

---

### Result output

```
    Name    Desc                                                  Pronouns
--  ------  ----------------------------------------------------  ----------
 0  Sarah   she doesn't like this because her mum...              female
 1  David   he does like it because his dad...                    male
 2  Sam     they generally don't like it because their parent...  plural/nb
```

Let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: @BenjaminPng Was everything clear? Did you discover why your code wasn't working?

Comment: Actually could you please elaborate a little on your detect_pronouns function? My knowledge of regex doesn't extend beyond pandas and I found it rather confusing. For example, what does curr_pron and curr_patt mean? It would be great if you could point me in the right direction with regards to learning more about these concepts. I haven't been able to find anything informative on google. Thanks!

Comment: @BenjaminPng I made an edit, let me know what you think :)

Comment: Thanks Alexander! Super helpful. I really appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: Nope! You've explained everything perfectly. Thanks!